# Is there a Nim library containing an `argsort` implementation or wrapper?

Tags: sorting, nim-lang

I am looking for a version of `argsort`, such [as exists in numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) or [in fortran](https://github.com/certik/fortran-utils/blob/master/src/sorting.f90). Is there an implementation of `argsort` in Nim ... or accessible to Nim in some library? It seems a bit surprising that it is missing.

**UPDATE**

The following seems to work for `argsort`:

```
proc argsort[T](a : T) : seq[int] =
  result = toSeq(0..a.len - 1)
  sort(result, proc (i, j: int): int = cmp(a[i], a[j]))
```

Presumably, though, it could be more efficient written natively and avoiding the function pointer....

Comment: If you've found a solution to this, I suggest writing an answer so that this question can be closed.

Comment: @Samadi - The update suggests a workaround... but perhaps having an open question might inspire someone to write a wrapper around a native implementation? Or is it more important to have a closed question?

Comment: That's a good point @shaunc, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: whats not "native" about that implementation? it's better than my answer!

Answer (score 3):

It hasn't made it's way into nimble yet, but Arraymancer has an `argsort`
[here](https://github.com/mratsim/Arraymancer/blob/master/src/arraymancer/tensor/algorithms.nim)

```
import arraymancer,algorithm,sequtils

proc argsort*[T](t: Tensor[T], order = SortOrder.Ascending): Tensor[int] =
  ## Returns the indices which would sort `t`. Useful to apply the same sorting to
  ## multiple tensors based on the order of the tensor `t`.
  ##
  ## Sorts the raw underlying data!
  # TODO: should we clone `t` so that if `t` is a view we don't access the whole
  # data?
  assert t.rank == 1, "Only 1D tensors can be sorted at the moment!"
  proc cmpIdxTup(x, y: (T, int)): int = system.cmp(x[0], y[0])
  # make a tuple of input & indices
  var tups = zip(toOpenArray(t.storage.Fdata, 0, t.size - 1),
                 toSeq(0 ..< t.size))
  # sort by custom sort proc
  tups.sort(cmp = cmpIdxTup, order = order)
  result = newTensorUninit[int](t.size)
  for i in 0 ..< t.size:
    result[i] = tups[i][1]

let x = @[3,9,4,1,5].toTensor()

echo x.argsort()
```

produces:

```
Tensor[system.int] of shape [5]" on backend "Cpu"
    3   0   2   4   1
```

[try it out here](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2wdm)